# HERE map.getcenter() returns 0

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm using the geocoder platform to get the lat/lng of an address. I then set the map center to those coordinates.

However, when I call map.getCenter() afterwards, I only get 0 for lat, lng and alt. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet?

Comment: `var location = result.items[0];
   
map.setCenter(location.position);
   
createResizablePolygon(map,location.position);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask for map's center right after setting new center, you'll get the old (or better said current) one.

You should wait till the map's center is really updated or use `mapviewchangeend` event listener:

```js
map.setCenter({lat:15,lng:16});

map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', (e) => {
  console.log(map.getCenter());
})
```

Comment: That makes sense. I was wondering if there was something like that that I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Could you also, please, mark the answer as accepted? Thank you!